# Write error when cloning repository

Tags: git

```
$ sudo git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/jeremy/xen.git linux-2.6-xen
remote:Counting objects:2275852,done.
remote:Compressing objects:100%(362867/362867) done.
Receiving objects:100%(2275852/2275852), 453.53MB | 37kiB/s, done
remote:Total 2275852 (delta 1901047),reused 2265649 (delta 1891419)
Resolving deltas:100% (1901047/1901047)done.
error:unable to write sha1 filename /usr/src/linux-2.6-xen/.git/objects/pack/pck-176ee0822d6d3afed83c05b32f2125e49ede7f7c.pack: No such file or directory
fatal :cannot store pack file
fatal :index-pack failed
```

Comment: This usually happens when you halt a git clone for some reason, try deleting the folder and cloning it again.

Comment: another solution? the problem is still here.

Comment: You could also check if you have enough free space left on your disk.

Comment: Thanks ,but there is enough space for this file.

Comment: And I didn't git clone anyway...what's the problem?

Comment: did you use `sudo` or not while generating your key initially?? like in the command `ssh-keygen`

Comment: @Dave: I don't think whether using `sudo` or not when generating the key initially has anything to do with the problem at hand. He is cloning from a public git link after all, there is no need for keys.

Comment: and download the file is so slow , could you tell me some method to speed up the download?

Comment: you mean that sudo may cause the problem?

Comment: @DanielLe there will be change in the key if you use sudo & if you dont.

Comment: I faced the same issue when I tried to clone to a network share

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your user has write permissions for the /usr/src directory?
Try cloning to some other directory with full read/write access. (e.g: /tmp)

Comment: It's a public branch to get the code. So I think the permission is not the key problem.